# when allocate memory to variables defined in the namespace

Tags: c++, static

For example, assume  `a` is a public static member in `ClassA`.

```
namespace SPACE{

   char* ClassA::a=NULL;

   ClassA::ClassA()
   {
     ClassA::a="initialized here";
   }
}
```

So two question：

1. when is `a=NULL` being invoked? Before `main()` or after that?
2. since a is a static member, why it can be defined twice with `NULL` and `“initialized here"`？

Comment: That code is incorrect. `ClassA::a = NULL;` at namespace level should not compile. Are you missing the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when is `a=NULL` being invoked? Before `main()` or after that?

Chances are, it's never going to be invoked: since this is a const-initialized value, it may be initialized by the loader of the executable on your system without running any code. Had it been initialized with some code, e.g. `a = my_init_func();`, that would complete before the `main()`.

> since a is a static member, why it can be defined twice with `NULL` and “initialized here"？

The second one is an assignment, not a declaration.

Answer (score 5):

1. Before `main()`
2. It's only **defined** once - at namespace scope. The second one is an **assignment**. It gets called when the constructor runs, and it modifies an already existing (defined and initialized) variable.